# LLVM IR with Itanium terminates the program unexpectedly

Tags: llvm

I've got a source program which my frontend has translated into LLVM IR. However, the IR unexpectedly ends up calling `std::terminate` as part of the Itanium ABI EH mechanism I've used. I've been staring at the IR for quite some time without any revelations as to why this has occurred.

Here's my original IR, simplified only by MCJIT's own passes:

```
; ModuleID = 'Wide'
target datalayout = "e-m:e-p:32:32-i64:64-f80:32-n8:16:32-S32"
target triple = "i686-pc-windows-itanium-elf"

%struct.__08F8D200 = type { i8 }
%struct.__08FBDC68 = type { [1 x i8] }

@_ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE = external global i8*
@_ZTS10__08FBDC68 = internal constant [13 x i8] c"10__08FBDC68\00"
@_ZTI10__08FBDC68 = internal constant { i8*, i8* } { i8* bitcast (i8** getelementptr inbounds (i8** @_ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE, i32 2) to i8*), i8* getelementptr inbounds ([13 x i8]* @_ZTS10__08FBDC68, i32 0, i32 0) }

define i8 @"16ef5f49-dbe3-4014-a9c8-a2dbb0c1d337"() {
out_of_bounds:
  %0 = alloca [1 x i8], align 1
  %1 = alloca %struct.__08F8D200, align 1
  %2 = alloca %struct.__08FBDC68, align 1
  %3 = bitcast %struct.__08F8D200* %1 to i8*
  %4 = bitcast [1 x i8]* %0 to i8*
  store i8 1, i8* %3
  %5 = load %struct.__08F8D200* %1
  %6 = extractvalue %struct.__08F8D200 %5, 0
  store i8 %6, i8* %4
  %7 = call i8* @__cxa_allocate_exception(i32 1)
  %8 = bitcast i8* %7 to %struct.__08FBDC68*
  store %struct.__08FBDC68 undef, %struct.__08FBDC68* %2
  invoke void @"5ea3408f-3d4e-4ef7-96b7-9c3dd87ae960"(%struct.__08FBDC68* %8, %struct.__08FBDC68* %2)
          to label %continue unwind label %landingpad

catch_block:                                      ; preds = %catch_continue
  %9 = landingpad { i8*, i32 } personality i32 (...)* @__gxx_personality_v0
          catch i8* null
  call void @__cxa_end_catch()
  %10 = extractvalue { i8*, i32 } %9, 1
  %11 = extractvalue { i8*, i32 } %9, 0
  ret i8 0

catch_block1:                                     ; preds = %landingpad3, %landingpad
  %12 = phi { i8*, i32 } [ %19, %landingpad ], [ %20, %landingpad3 ]
  %13 = extractvalue { i8*, i32 } %12, 1
  %14 = extractvalue { i8*, i32 } %12, 0
  %15 = call i32 @llvm.eh.typeid.for(i8* bitcast ({ i8*, i8* }* @_ZTI10__08FBDC68 to i8*))
  %16 = icmp eq i32 %13, %15
  br i1 %16, label %catch_target, label %catch_continue

continue:                                         ; preds = %out_of_bounds
  %17 = bitcast i8* %7 to %struct.__08FBDC68*
  %18 = bitcast %struct.__08FBDC68* %17 to i8*
  invoke void @__cxa_throw(i8* %18, i8* bitcast ({ i8*, i8* }* @_ZTI10__08FBDC68 to i8*), i8* null)
          to label %unreachable unwind label %landingpad3

landingpad:                                       ; preds = %out_of_bounds
  %19 = landingpad { i8*, i32 } personality i32 (...)* @__gxx_personality_v0
          catch i8* bitcast ({ i8*, i8* }* @_ZTI10__08FBDC68 to i8*)
          catch i8* null
  call void @__cxa_free_exception(i8* %7)
  br label %catch_block1

landingpad3:                                      ; preds = %continue
  %20 = landingpad { i8*, i32 } personality i32 (...)* @__gxx_personality_v0
          catch i8* bitcast ({ i8*, i8* }* @_ZTI10__08FBDC68 to i8*)
          catch i8* null
  br label %catch_block1

unreachable:                                      ; preds = %continue
  unreachable

catch_target:                                     ; preds = %catch_block1
  %21 = call i8* (i8*, ...)* @__cxa_begin_catch(i8* %14)
  call void @__cxa_end_catch()
  ret i8 1

catch_continue:                                   ; preds = %catch_block1
  %22 = call i8* (i8*, ...)* @__cxa_begin_catch(i8* %14)
  invoke void @__cxa_rethrow()
          to label %unreachable5 unwind label %catch_block

unreachable5:                                     ; preds = %catch_continue
  unreachable
}

declare i8* @__cxa_allocate_exception(i32)

define void @"5ea3408f-3d4e-4ef7-96b7-9c3dd87ae960"(%struct.__08FBDC68*, %struct.__08FBDC68*) {
entry:
  ret void
}

declare i32 @__gxx_personality_v0(...)

declare void @__cxa_free_exception(i8*)

declare void @__cxa_throw(i8*, i8*, i8*)

; Function Attrs: nounwind readnone
declare i32 @llvm.eh.typeid.for(i8*) #0

declare i8* @__cxa_begin_catch(i8*, ...)

declare void @__cxa_end_catch()

declare void @__cxa_rethrow()

attributes #0 = { nounwind readnone }

!llvm.ident = !{!0}

!0 = metadata !{metadata !"clang version 3.5.0 (tags/RELEASE_350/final)"}
```

There's quite a bit of dead code but so far I haven't finished building the tools I need to convert a reduced version into something I can execute and check the result of.

The only output libstdc++'s EH routines give is "std::terminate called after throwing instace of __08FBDC68". Sure, I threw one, but there's be a landing pad right there to catch it. I don't understand why the implementation is not finding the landing pad.

Why is my landing pad not being landed on? If I convert this IR into an executable on Linux and execute the output, then all seems to work fine. When I MCJIT it on Windows, epic fail.

Edit: I've altered my test case very slightly, and now it passes.

```
; ModuleID = 'Wide'
target datalayout = "e-m:e-p:32:32-i64:64-f80:32-n8:16:32-S32"
target triple = "i686-pc-windows-itanium-elf"

%struct.__08E11DF0 = type { [1 x i8] }

@_ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE = external global i8*
@_ZTS10__08E11DF0 = internal constant [13 x i8] c"10__08E11DF0\00"
@_ZTI10__08E11DF0 = internal constant { i8*, i8* } { i8* bitcast (i8** getelementptr inbounds (i8** @_ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE, i32 2) to i8*), i8* getelementptr inbounds ([13 x i8]* @_ZTS10__08E11DF0, i32 0, i32 0) }

define i8 @a3b850db-5539-466c-bc66-173731166e7d() {
entry:
  %0 = alloca %struct.__08E11DF0, align 1
  %1 = call i8* @__cxa_allocate_exception(i32 1)
  %2 = bitcast i8* %1 to %struct.__08E11DF0*
  store %struct.__08E11DF0 undef, %struct.__08E11DF0* %0
  invoke void @"799641a0-f6b5-4af2-ad73-e9bede067f08"(%struct.__08E11DF0* %2, %struct.__08E11DF0* %0)
          to label %continue unwind label %landingpad

catch_block:                                      ; preds = %catch_continue
  %3 = landingpad { i8*, i32 } personality i32 (...)* @__gxx_personality_v0
          catch i8* null
  call void @__cxa_end_catch()
  %4 = extractvalue { i8*, i32 } %3, 1
  %5 = extractvalue { i8*, i32 } %3, 0
  ret i8 0

catch_block1:                                     ; preds = %landingpad3, %landingpad
  %6 = phi { i8*, i32 } [ %13, %landingpad ], [ %14, %landingpad3 ]
  %7 = extractvalue { i8*, i32 } %6, 1
  %8 = extractvalue { i8*, i32 } %6, 0
  %9 = call i32 @llvm.eh.typeid.for(i8* bitcast ({ i8*, i8* }* @_ZTI10__08E11DF0 to i8*))
  %10 = icmp eq i32 %7, %9
  br i1 %10, label %catch_target, label %catch_continue

continue:                                         ; preds = %entry
  %11 = bitcast i8* %1 to %struct.__08E11DF0*
  %12 = bitcast %struct.__08E11DF0* %11 to i8*
  invoke void @__cxa_throw(i8* %12, i8* bitcast ({ i8*, i8* }* @_ZTI10__08E11DF0 to i8*), i8* null)
          to label %unreachable unwind label %landingpad3

landingpad:                                       ; preds = %entry
  %13 = landingpad { i8*, i32 } personality i32 (...)* @__gxx_personality_v0
          catch i8* bitcast ({ i8*, i8* }* @_ZTI10__08E11DF0 to i8*)
          catch i8* null
  call void @__cxa_free_exception(i8* %1)
  br label %catch_block1

landingpad3:                                      ; preds = %continue
  %14 = landingpad { i8*, i32 } personality i32 (...)* @__gxx_personality_v0
          catch i8* bitcast ({ i8*, i8* }* @_ZTI10__08E11DF0 to i8*)
          catch i8* null
  br label %catch_block1

unreachable:                                      ; preds = %continue
  unreachable

catch_target:                                     ; preds = %catch_block1
  %15 = call i8* (i8*, ...)* @__cxa_begin_catch(i8* %8)
  call void @__cxa_end_catch()
  ret i8 1

catch_continue:                                   ; preds = %catch_block1
  %16 = call i8* (i8*, ...)* @__cxa_begin_catch(i8* %8)
  invoke void @__cxa_rethrow()
          to label %unreachable5 unwind label %catch_block

unreachable5:                                     ; preds = %catch_continue
  unreachable
}

declare i8* @__cxa_allocate_exception(i32)

define void @"799641a0-f6b5-4af2-ad73-e9bede067f08"(%struct.__08E11DF0*, %struct.__08E11DF0*) {
entry:
  ret void
}

declare i32 @__gxx_personality_v0(...)

declare void @__cxa_free_exception(i8*)

declare void @__cxa_throw(i8*, i8*, i8*)

; Function Attrs: nounwind readnone
declare i32 @llvm.eh.typeid.for(i8*) #0

declare i8* @__cxa_begin_catch(i8*, ...)

declare void @__cxa_end_catch()

declare void @__cxa_rethrow()

attributes #0 = { nounwind readnone }

!llvm.ident = !{!0}

!0 = metadata !{metadata !"clang version 3.5.0 (tags/RELEASE_350/final)"}
```

As you can see, it's basically identical, with only the value numbers and a bit of dead code in the entry block is different. I'm starting to think this may be an LLVM bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in MCJIT- the program executes just fine if you invoke MCJIT only once.